# Android Manifest Restrict To Tablets

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

For business reasons I'd like to restrict my Android application strictly to tablet devices.

At the moment, I can limit the app to Honeycomb devices by setting:

```
android:minSdkVersion="11"
```

But the next version of Android (Ice Cream Sandwich) will have a higher version number for both the tablet and phone versions of the OS.

Is there any manifest attribute I can specify to restrict it to tablet devices? (Honeycomb or any later tablet version)

Comment: Here's the [blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html) specially for you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You will find this link awesome: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html

The problem with what we call "tablet" is that the definition is not the same for evryone.
I think about the Archos 5IT that is the same size than a phone but branded with "tablet" name. Same issue with Dell Streak.

I would personnaly not call that a tablet..

So if you want to restrict to 7 or 5 inches devices, you should use xlargeScreens and largeScreens.

(There is also a bug in HTC flyer - 7 inches- that uses largeScreens, blame HTC)

I guess that playing with Screen size in Manifest will fit your needs:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

[image]

Comment: I had to use the above code to stop OS 3.2 from giving me a view comp. popup (something specific to 3.2 at the moment)

android:xlargeScreens="true"

Comment: i am not get this option in my manifet file android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"
i am use Android 3.0 version...

Comment: replace integer with something.. Or remove the line!

Answer (score 2):

```
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"
```

Be careful, Android Market currently does not support this attribute for filtering (from the official guide).

use support screen large and xlarge and now you have two options:

- exclude the large screen devices which are not tablets manually from Market(+500...)
- You can measure programmatically the width and if it width<600 say the user that the app is not compatible.

While that we'll have to wait for the Market to filter by android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" ...

Comment: *Be careful* with this approach from now on! A 7" tablet with full HD resolution (1920x1080) has around 315 ppi, thus being a XHDPI/320 device. 1080 / (320/160) equals 540 dp and excludes it from the sw600dp limit. From now on, 7"@1080p tablets will probably be common (Nexus 7 fullHD rumor rings a bell), so it would be embarrassing to tell such user that his tablet is not a tablet!

Answer (score 2):

please review the docs - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html.

```
<manifest ... >
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
...
<application ... >
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the PhoneGap official documentation can help you out: http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.