# How do I restrict my Android app to non-tablets?

Tags: android, download, google-play

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649558/android-manifest-restrict-to-tablets) which show how I can restrict download to only tablets, but I am looking the other way round.

How can I restrict my app to only download on mobiles and not on tablets? (It's the requirement from the client.)

Answer (score 5):

Add [a `<compatible-screens>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) to your manifest, outlining the specific screen sizes and densities that you support.

Comment: thanx cant use this though as I am on version 8

Comment: @Raj: Change your build target to API Level 9 and use it.

Comment: Sorry can't ... As per the requirement

Comment: @Raj: You act as though you have a choice, and you do not, other than to not ship your app or to allow it to work on all screen sizes (including tablets). Your build target does **not** affect what devices can use your app -- you can have a build target of 9 and still ship to API Level 8 devices (or even API Level 1 devices, if you wish).

Comment: Thanks for all the help... I can't set <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" /> as if the app is installed on 2.2 android device the features which are only supported from 2.3 will crash the app. apart from that ... I would like to stick to 2.2 as 20% of my app was downloaded by 2.2 devices.. which hell lots of market...

Comment: I have finally used the following... But I dont know if this will sove the issue... <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

Comment: @Raj: "I can't set <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />" -- I never told you to set `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />`. That has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with your build target, and your build target is what controls whether you can use `<compatible-screens>`. "But I dont know if this will sove the issue" -- it certainly will not "restrict my app to only download on mobiles and not on tablets".

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution you could use is to add the following to manifest:

```
    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="true" />
```

This will restrict the apk to being installed on devices that the ability to make phone calls(i.e. non-tablets).

Comment: What about tablets that can make phone calls? :)

Comment: But wouldn't that just make it a really large phone? ;)

Comment: I would still consider it a tablet, though. Your point being undeniable. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare's Answer is 100% correct.

You have other options also, Use

[supports-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Or Manually filter the tablet devices in Google Play. This will be tedious task.

Comment: `<supports-screens>` can filter out smaller sizes, but not larger ones.

Comment: what about:<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false"/> It would restrict the app to non-xlargeScreens devices, wouldn't it? thus hiding the app from tablets?

Comment: It would not. It makes larger devices user scaling on apps layouts