# restrict app to mobile

Tags: android, ios

I want to prevent a messaging app (ios & android) being used via a device that does not have a sim card. This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142755/how-do-i-restrict-my-android-app-to-non-tablets) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846609/restrict-app-installing-in-tablets) both suggest the following might work for android, but I also need an ios equivalent :

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
android:required="true"/>
```

Can such code to be copied to a tablet/desktop and then circumvented ? I am aware that wattsapp's mobile-only approach could be circumvented for use on a PC and I want to avoid such possibility.

Comment: You should not use `android` tag and provide Android examples in iOS development question as they can mislead people.

Comment: @mixel. Thank you & apologies to anyone misled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode click on the project and open `General` page. There in `Deployment Info - Devices` choose `iPhone`.

To restrict devices only to those that had telephony you should add to `Info.plist` `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` (aka `Required Device Capabilities`) dictionary entry with key `telephony` set to `YES`.

Comment: Thanks @mixel. Any chance that this can be circumvented by copying to a non-mobile device as wattsapp could ?

Comment: This still allows an app to be installed on the iPod touch

Comment: Updated answer. Now it should be correct.

Comment: Sure, after it was closed after a duplicate you updated your answer to match the duplicate.