# Tablet only app's layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm planning to create an android application which needs to be run on tablet devices only. If so, in which folder I have to create the layouts?

- res/layout
  or
- res/layout-large

I'll put the screen restrictions in the manifest file. If I have to keep the layout files in res/layout-large, can I remove the folder res/layout?
Which is the best way to create tablet only android app's layouts?
Please guide me.

Comment: Always search first. This previous question should answer this for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649558/android-manifest-restrict-to-tablets

Comment: @anthropomo: I searched a lot, I clearly mentioned in my question that I'll put screen restriction in manifest file. What I asked is in which folder we have to keep the layout files if the app is going to design only for tablets. I know we have to keep layouts in layout-large folder for tablets, but I didn't have any idea in the case of tablet only app. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target are only tablets you can use `res/layout` straight, if you are supporting different layouts for different tablets (large / xlarge / etc..) then use the folder with qualifier.