# Flex mobile app only for tablets

Tags: android, apache-flex, tablet, flexbuilder

I would like to release my brand new Flex mobile app only for tablets (IPads and Android).
How can I configure the Application Descriptor File properly?

For IOS I know it's possible:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
  <array>
    <string>2</string>
  </array>
```

but for Android I have no idea...

Thanks,

Gabriele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your manifest

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

this will make the app only available to 7" screens and above

Answer (score 0):

What do you define by tablet ? Some android tablets have the **same** screen size as some android phones. So you have to fit your requirements. Are you talking about the size of the screen ? If yes you should restrict your app for largeScreens and xlargeScreens.

You can read [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649558/android-manifest-restrict-to-tablets)

Comment: With "tablet" I mean a device with 7”-or-greater screen. Thanks