# how to create a tablet-only project?

Tags: android

I am creating an app in Android Studio.
While creating the app I select the phone and tablet option in Android Studio.  But I need to set the project to be tablet-only.
How to make it tablet-only?

Comment: i tested but not got.can give steps to do

Comment: here u can find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7649632/4853552

Answer (score 0):

Please keep below lines in your AndroidManifest.xml file to support only for tablet.

```
<manifest ... >
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
...
<application ... >
    ...
</application>
```